# Blockchain.com passphrase pattern ?

Tags: passphrase

is there any way to know blockchain.com passphrase pattern , I mean they use some words from the dictionary to give someone a passphrase , how would we know the exact wordslist they use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current blockchain.info wallets use the BIP39 wordlist, which you can find for various languages at https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/bip-0039-wordlists.md/

Previous versions have used non-standard implementations with a variety of different wordlists for example [v2](https://github.com/blockchain/unused-My-Wallet/blob/master/mnemonic.js#L319-L534) and [v3](https://github.com/blockchain/unused-My-Wallet/blob/master/mnemonic_words_v3.html).

Comment: is there any type of salt they uses at the time of making keypair ? or they just use 12 words passphrase to make the keypair ?

Comment: Current implementations follow BIP39 and 32, you can read those to see how keys are derived from the words